# Program not recognizing statement as a subcommand of if-elif statement. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the program below.

Somehow, the program executes the `if distance == "..."`: commands even though I wanted them only to be executed `if pickup_location = "no"`.
Probably there is just some basic thing I missed in my program, which brought me here, as I could not fix it and want to ask for your help. 
I'm perfectly fine with a hint, so I can figure it out.

```
#This program calculates the final price, based on the base price of a car's production price
#21.07 Author: 382df7181fcd71a41cfe9b793032c029d139ecb557a4af40ca5de3a148bbbc0d (SHA256)

production_price = int(input("How much did it cost to produce the car?"))

#parameters to be set
sales_margin_percentage = 0.2
tax_rate = 0.23
license_rate = 0.12
dealers_cut = 0.05
delivery_fee_10_100 = 400
delivery_fee_100_250 = 1050
#calculations of extra fees
sales_margin = production_price * sales_margin_percentage
internal_sales_price = production_price+sales_margin
tax = internal_sales_price * tax_rate
license_fee = internal_sales_price * license_rate
pre_external_sales_price = internal_sales_price + tax + license_fee
dealer_prep = pre_external_sales_price * dealers_cut
final_price = pre_external_sales_price + dealer_prep

pickup_location = input("Do you want to collect the car at the dealer ship?")
if pickup_location == "yes":
        print("Ok. Then the final price would be.", final_price, "We'll give you a call right away when we see the delivery truck from which point on you are free to"
                                                                 "collect it at any point in time.")
elif pickup_location == "no":
    distance = int(input("How far away do you live away from the dealership in kilometers?"))
    if distance <= 10:
            print("Nice. Tha:t will mean that you can profit of our free home delivery service and can receive " 
                  "your car for the final price of", final_price, "dollars.")
    elif distance > 10 and distance <= 100:
    print("Awesome. You can buy and get your car delivered to the front door for the final price of", final_price + delivery_fee_10_100,
          "Dollars.")
    elif distance > 100 and distance >200:
    print("Awesome. That means that you can buy and get the car delivered for the final price of", final_price + delivery_fee_100_250,
           " to your front lawn.")
    else:
    print("I'm sorry. A home delivery is not possible for your location, however, you can pick it up at the dealer ship "
           "for the final price of", final_price, "Dollars, should you still want to buy it.")

else:
    print("What?")
```

Comment: You got an indentation problem in your first print. Remove a tab...

Comment: Same with the other if statements.  Sub-statements should be indented exactly one level more than their corresponding encapsulating if/elif/else.

Comment: Thank you @EvgenyKolyakov. I knew it was something very simple and stupid. However, I did not think about formatting. Thanks again.

Comment: Also Thank you @JAponte.

Comment: @JAponte done. ✌️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working program for python 3

```
#This program calculates the final price, based on the base price of a car's production price
#21.07 Author: 382df7181fcd71a41cfe9b793032c029d139ecb557a4af40ca5de3a148bbbc0d (SHA256)

#parameters to be set
sales_margin_percentage = 0.2
tax_rate = 0.23
license_rate = 0.12
dealers_cut = 0.05
delivery_fee_10_100 = 400
delivery_fee_100_250 = 1050

production_price = int(input("How much did it cost to produce the car?"))

#calculations of extra fees
sales_margin = production_price * sales_margin_percentage
internal_sales_price = production_price+sales_margin
tax = internal_sales_price * tax_rate
license_fee = internal_sales_price * license_rate
pre_external_sales_price = internal_sales_price + tax + license_fee
dealer_prep = pre_external_sales_price * dealers_cut
final_price = pre_external_sales_price + dealer_prep

pickup_location = str(input("Do you want to collect the car at the dealer ship?"))
if pickup_location == "yes":
    print("Ok. Then the final price would be.",
          final_price,
          "We'll give you a call right away when we see the delivery truck from which point on you are free to"
          "collect it at any point in time.")
elif pickup_location == "no":
    distance = int(input("How far away do you live away from the dealership in kilometers?"))
    if distance <= 10:
        print("Nice. That will mean that you can profit of our free home delivery service and can receive "
              "your car for the final price of", final_price, "dollars.")
    elif 10 < distance <= 100:
        print("Awesome. You can buy and get your car delivered to the front door for the final price of", final_price + delivery_fee_10_100,
              "Dollars.")
    elif 100 < distance <= 200:
        print("Awesome. That means that you can buy and get the car delivered for the final price of", final_price + delivery_fee_100_250,
              " to your front lawn.")
    else:
        print("I'm sorry. A home delivery is not possible for your location, however, you can pick it up at the dealer ship "
              "for the final price of", final_price, "Dollars, should you still want to buy it.")
else:
    print("What?")
```

Note: I fixed the final distance conditional as `distance > 100 and distance > 200` is redundant and I think you meant `<= 200`.  You might want to fix your parameters on the final if else statements.  They don't correspond to the printed statements (e.g. `delivery_fee_100_250`).

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I realised that as well later on and changed it. Still. Thank you for your time to correct my program.